# Passing form field to external URL in Django Wagtail

Tags: django, forms, redirect

I'm trying to pass a field from a form on a Wagtail brochure site to another form that is at the same domain (subdomain) but not part of the actual brochure site. The user inputs an insurance type and a zip code, and they are redirected to a site to get a quote. I need to pass that type and zip code to the form on redirect. The only examples I've seen are redirects to templates on the same site; never an external site URL. Right now when I hit submit on the form, the form disappears, but doesn't redirect me anywhere. What am I missing?

View:

```
from django import template
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import QuoteForm

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('quote_form.html')
def get_a_quote(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = QuoteForm(request.POST)

       if form.is_valid():
           type = form.cleaned_data['type']
           if type == 'auto':
               zip_code = form.cleaned_data['zip_code']
               return redirect(f'http://samplesite.com/?zip_code={zip_code}')
           else:
               return redirect(f'http://samplesite.com/')
   else:
       form = QuoteForm()
   return {'form': form}
```

Model:

```
from django import forms


TYPES = (
    ('auto', 'Auto Insurance'),
    ('home', 'Home Insurance'),
)


class QuoteForm(forms.Form):
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPES)
    zip_code = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Your Zip Code'}
        ), max_length=6, required=False)
```

Template: (quote_form.html)

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>{{ form.type }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>{{ form.zip_code }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The secondary site must be configured to take as an argument in the GET request the zip code, which I am assuming you have but just saying for sanity's sake.  Otherwise, try formatting the URL you want before redirecting to it.  Sometimes python's order of operations is not what you'd expect when passing unformatted strings through a function.

Comment: You can use [requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)  and pass the request that will be more appropriate make sure you have `cors headers` enabled at the url you are pointing to can you post the log you are getting in browser console or network so that we can be sure that url is successful

Comment: I have tried formatting the URL with `urllib.parse.quote` but it still does not redirect me. The secondary site is configured to take the zip code in as an argument, but shouldn't it redirect me to the secondary site URL even if that wasn't the case?